# When scrolling content goes overtop of fixed background

Tags: css

I feel like this should be an easy answer but cant figure out how to achieve this effect.

Essentially i'm trying to do this: http://demo.smooththemes.com/theone/

one this site, when you start scrolling the image stays fixed and the content scrolls over top.  Any ideas?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

example
http://jsfiddle.net/gvMLS/

HTML

```
 <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>content<br/>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 20px;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
#content {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
background-color:#fff;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I might not have explained that well enough though.  I was referring to the background image of the computer behind the text "WE ARE THEONE AGENCY AND WE DO BRANDING & THEMES" and how it stays fixed whil the content below flows.  Does that make sense? Sorry if im not explaining it correctly.  Thanks for the quick response.